# Switching between taps of transformer

Tags: transformer

What's the difference between this two methods of "tap switching"? do they work the same?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzTdG6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No they don't work the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the circuits are not the same.

I removed the "fluff" (the rectifiers are irrelevant) and added labels.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcB0Hk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top circuit can output **4** different voltages **if** the voltages across the separate windings are all different.

The bottom circuit can only output **3** different voltages, when S2b is in the "C" position, switch S2a **does nothing**.

Comment: +1 Even if A:B is 5V, B:C is 5V, C:D is 10V , then you can get 5, 10, 15, or 20V from the top circuit, but only 10, 10, 15, 20 from the bottom circuit.